# Distributing javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, distribution, each

I'm trying to come up with a way of appending the data from an array built, within `$.each()`, without repeating, to `ul.featured-list`

```
<div id="home-page-featured">
    <ul class="featured-list"></ul>
    <ul class="featured-list"></ul>
    <ul class="featured-list"></ul>
</div>
```

The content of the `li` will be the following:

```
<li>
   <a href="http://local.site.com/chocolate-cakes/">
       <img width="186" height="186" src="http://local.site.com/view/img/blank.jpg" />
   </a>
</li>
```

I calculate how many `li`s each `ul` may contain, with the following:

```
var amount = Math.floor($(document).width() / 186) + 2;
```

Then I get the content that will form the `li`s with ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url  : '/json/projects/' + (amount * 3),
    type : 'GET',

    success: function(reply, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var projects = [];
        $.each(reply, function(i, v) {
            if(v['gallery'][0])
            {
                console.log(v['gallery'][0]);
                projects.push(
                    '<li>'
                        +'<a href="/project/'+v['id']+'" title="'+v['name']+'">'
                            +'<img src="/data/images/'+v['gallery'][0].name+'" />'
                        +'</a>'
                    +'</li>'
                );
            }
        });
        console.log(projects);
    }
});
```

Now the only dilemma remaining, is how to redistribute those `li`s inside `projects` in all my `ul.featured-list`

Let's say that the maximum `li`s that each `ul.featured-list` may contain, is 10, then if `projects` contains 11 `li`s, 10 will go to first `ul.featured-list` and what's left will continue on the second row, and so on.

### My thoughts:

- `$.each()` for the `ul`s won't work, because will repeat content
- I could try starting to append content to first `ul`, and when it reaches `amount` to stop, and removing what have already been appended and continue with the process with the second `ul`, but I don't think that would be such an elegant way of doing it

So, what do you think? What suggestions of approaching this problem do you have?

## Update

This is the current solution I am using, but I don't feel is that efficient... how can it be optimized?
http://jsfiddle.net/nV5RU/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var arrayToFill = [...];  

$("ul.list").each(function (index) {  //  loop through all <ul> items
    $(this).find("li").each(function (index) { //  loop through all  <li> items inside
        $(this).html(arrayToFill.shift()); // fill & delete one on each turn
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nV5RU/10/

Comment: Your suggestion, is much more efficient as is less code written, but it has a fault, and that is that on the swap from one `ul` to another, the next data to append to `li`, is skipped... which in this case is `milky-way` and `hihihi`

Comment: anyway, I suggested an edit to your answer with the not complete working version

Comment: My fault, had to switch the arguments in the 'while' clause, so it won't 'shift' if the 10 was reached. now it works

Comment: If you would've read my suggestion to your post, you would've seen that I don't need to append, I need to modify `li`'s value... where with this code gets even worse.

Comment: Sorry, I am quite new here. Where can I find this *suggestion*? Btw. didn't even know it exists.

Comment: when you edited your post, before looking into my suggestion (you get a notification when someone suggests an edit), I think you might have deleted it, but look in your notification panel for the suggestion notify, click it and see if you can rescue it. I am not gonna write it again, sorry, and I didn't save the js fiddle link either

Comment: Well, seems gone. Sorry for that. At least "I" learned something ;)

Comment: Ok, I hope I got you right this time. I updated your jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/nV5RU/10/

Comment: Oh, lol... shame on me, went the hard way to achieve the desired result when it could be achieved so easy :|, please update your answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is quite efficient and acceptable if you keep your code optimized. I mean instead of calling `$('ul.featured-list')` each time in loop you can cache it in some variable and then use that variable.

Or you can move your appending logic into some other `function` and call that `function` in `loop` by passing it elements in the form of array and the `ul element` to append those items to.

For me you are already going in right direction :-).

You can use `slice` method on `array` object to slice elements from `array` while still preserving original `array`.

Comment: @w0rldart: My pleasure. I have updated my answer. Please! have a look at it. Thanks.